# When to allow MediaSessionCompat.onPlay, and when to disallow at start for Android Auto?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-auto

I have an Android media app for playing music. I register a service inside `AndroidManifest.xml`. When my app is started and my service is sent `onCreate()` I create a MediaSessionCompat and register a callback:

```
mediaSession.setCallback(new EventCallback());
```

So far, so good. My app can be used and it plays music!

However, when I connect Android Auto (using the `desktop-head-unit`) to my app, `EventCallback.onPlay()` is called. [According to the Android Auto quality guidelines I have to make sure media is *not* auto played](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/car-app-quality#media-autoplay), so I have to intercept this to prevent playback from happening.

The same callback is called when someone presses the play button, and there's no contextual information for the event. **So how do I know when to prevent playback, and when to allow it?**

One way of figuring that out might be to identify who is requesting the playback, but I can't see any way of doing that in the callback. I looked into this further by logging the `getMediaSession().getCurrentControllerInfo()` but that returns the same package name, PID and UID regardless of whether this `onPlay` occurs at startup or via a manual click.

###### More information

I wondered if it was actually my code that was sending a request to play. After breakpointing all such requests and not seeing any such calls, I breakpointed the message dispatch system inside `MediaSession`. I can see this gets called:

```
Binder:16194_4 in group "main": RUNNING
    dispatchPlay:657, MediaSession (android.media.session)
    onPlay:1243, MediaSession$CallbackStub (android.media.session)
    onTransact:422, ISessionCallback$Stub (android.media.session)
    execTransactInternal:1056, Binder (android.os)
    execTransact:1029, Binder (android.os)
```

(warning: handcopied stacktrace).

However, I can't see what is dispatching the message to `onTransact` in the first place - all I can see is the `caller` is:

```
MediaSessionManager$RemoteUserInfo
    mPackageName = "com.google.android.projection.gearhead"
    mPid = 30672
    mUid = 10050
```